# URL rewrite matter

Tags: url-rewriting, cpanel

I am going to rewrite URLs of may web page for the first time. Before doing that I want to know whether it is possible to rewrite URL without requesting my web master or I must request my web master for any help regarding this. I don't want to request actually.

I have cpanel v 11 access. Is it possible for me to do url rewrite from cpanel? Which application in cpanel can help me to rewrite URL?